# How to find a single item in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm working with a list of objects and I need to select one of the objects and assign it to a variable to be used later. I understand that I need to use the `.Find()` method inside of the list, but I'm not sure what I'd need to put inside the parentheses in order to find the correct object. I'm using classes defined by an SDK to interact with an API, which is new to me. Here's my code:

```
var fileCabinets = org.GetFileCabinetsFromFilecabinetsRelation().FileCabinet;
foreach (var fc in fileCabinets)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have access to the file cabinet " + fc.Name + " " + fc.Id + ".");
}

fileCabinets.Find();
```

`fileCabinets` is a list of type `FileCabinet`. I need to select one of the FileCabinets in the list.

Comment: You do not define what you mean by "list". Do you mean a System.Collections.Generic.List? Or some other type of list? This will determine what methods you can use to find an item in the list. In other words, what is the type of fileCabinets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileCabinet fileCabinet = fileCabinets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.(propertyName) == (valueToMatch));
```

Like @Rainman said, if there is a probability that the name is not unique, use his solution. If you are sure that the Name property is unique, use this one.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `FirstOrDefault`

```
var fileCabinet = fileCabinets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

If you want to stay with `Find()`

```
var fileCabinet = fileCabinets.Find(x => x.Id == 1);
```

To filter list by using `Name` property

```
var fileCabinet = fileCabinets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Sample");
```

Comment: You beat me with just a few minutes. Why did you choose FirstOrDefault over SingleOrDefault?

Comment: There is no reason. I would say, habit :) In this case, of course we expect just one item.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with Maarten's solution because I don't necessarily want to use the Id property, in this case I'm actually using the Name property and his answer shower me how to do that, but both answers really helped. Thanks

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` will not crash the program, it just returns NULL.

Personally, I more like the `FirstOrDefault()` in general, but there are certainly some cases you want to use `SingleOrDefault()`;

Comment: SingleOrDefault() returns NULL as well, when no match is hit. FirstOrDefault() insinuates that the resultset could/should be a list and you need to take the first item. SingleOrDefault() insinuates there always should be 1 result to begin with, as you would use in a identification scenario.

Comment: @Tom D But in this scenario, you want to filter by using Name property. So, Name property most likely is not unique and there would be multiple records matching. So, in my opinion, it could be better to use FirstOrDefault() .

Comment: @MaartenHeebink Small correction: `SingleOrDefault` requires there are 0 or 1 matches. If there will be exactly 1 then use `Single`.

Comment: In this situation, the name is always unique as well, but I see why in other situations you'd want to use the ID to make sure that only 1 result is returned.